# Target both an id and a class

Tags: html, css

I have two separate pages with HTML:

```
<!-- in the body of page1.html -->
<div class="foo">
    <!-- content goes here -->
</div>
```

and:

```
<!-- in the body of page2.html -->
<div id="bar">
    <!-- some other content goes here -->
</div>
```

Currently I'm targeting these div elements using some common CSS:

```
.foo {
    width: 680px !important;
}
#bar {
    margin: auto;
    width: 680px !important;
}
```

Is there a shorter (DRY - don't repeat yourself) way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you add your `foo` class to the `bar` div? Or, just use `.foo, #bar { css }`.

Comment: @dognose  A child selector won't work in this example, as `#bar` is not a child of `foo`. I think OP wants `.foo, #bar { css }`.

Comment: Yes use comma separated selectors `.class, #id { rule}`

Comment: Use of a comma for the common CSS did the trick, thanks.

Comment: @Santi of course you are right, just forgot the comma.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this way:

```
.foo, #bar {
  width: 680px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be one of those "six of one, half dozen of the other" scenarios, but are you looking for this?:

```
.foo, #bar {
    width: 680px !important;
}
#bar {
    margin: auto;
}
```

You can have all the selectors you like on a single CSS block, separated by commas.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `.foo` class to `#bar` in your HTML:

```
<div id="bar" class="foo">
    <!-- some other content goes here -->
</div>
```

Remove `width` from `#bar` in your CSS:

```
.foo {
    width: 680px !important;
}
#bar {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is not the sort of solution I was thinking of, but I can see where you're coming from.

Answer (score 1):

This is helpful for you,

**CSS**

```
.foo, #bar {
  width: 680px !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="foo">
    <!-- content goes here -->
</div>

<div id="bar">
    <!-- some other content goes here -->
</div>
```

To group selectors, separate each selector with a comma.